# Serial communication read line C++

Tags: c++, python, symbian, pyserial, pys60

I want to read a line from serial with Symbian C++ but to do that I have to continue reading into a buffer until I reach "/n". I have no idea how to do this though. This is actually a Python project but I am trying to create a C++ library with with the neccesary functions ported from PySerial. Al I still have to port is "readline though.

Here is the original Python code for it:

```
def readline(self, size=None, eol=LF): 
     """read a line which is terminated with end-of-line (eol) character
     ('\n' by default) or until timeout."""
     leneol = len(eol)
     line = bytearray()

     while True: 
         c = self.read(1)
         if c: 
             line += c 
             if line[-leneol:] == eol: 
                 break 
             if size is not None and len(line) >= size: 
                 break 
         else: 
             break
     return bytes(line)
```

My library is based on PyS60USB which has already implemented the following to read at least one byte:

```
TUint8* buf = 0;
TPtr8 tmp(buf, 0);
TInt err;
TBool alloc_ok = EFalse;

Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS;         
TRAP(err,
   buf = (TUint8*) User::AllocLC(1);
   tmp.Set(buf, 0, 1);
   alloc_ok = ETrue;
   self->iConnManager->RecvL(tmp, timeout);
   CleanupStack::Pop(buf);
   );
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS;
```

My question though is now, how can I translate the afore mentioned Python code to Symbian C++ code that can add all the read bytes to a buffer and continously check the buffer for eol?

Thanks, all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: I want to communicate with an adruino, so I need a way to read the lines that it sends back to my device.

Comment: Yes, I meant why do you want to move the Python code to Symbian C++ - it's not like reading a serial line is going to stress the processor. Or have I misunderstood what you want to do?

Comment: No, I guess I could just use the Python code in my application but that would make my libary less portable and that is a problem because I need to run quite a few Python scripts that expect this functionality in the serial library. I also don't think porting this to c++ should be to hard though, I just have no idea.

Comment: I used to work for Symbian (in the graphics team, before you start complaining about the serial interface), and despite that, I feel that you would be better off using python to solve the problem than to solve it in C++. After all, if you are mainly writing code in python anyway, there should be no reason to NOT use another python library that solves this part of the problem - it is always easier to write a function [on almost all platforms] that reads one character from the serial port than something that reads a line.

Comment: But to do this in C++, you would have to allocate a buffer, then read one character at a time in a loop and check if it's newline. The code wouldn't be much different, just more difficult to write, because you have to write it in C++, which makes life more complex...

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't really another library availible for this and I don't actually code in Python, I'm more of a C# guy but WP doesn't have USB serial communication yet so... I am also simply trying to run some existing Python software that uses PySerial. Would you be able to give me an example of the code though please, I am mainly strugling with creating an expandable beuffer because the size of the line is unknown and I am not sure how to search for the eol in the buffer.

Comment: Exactly the issues with allocating a large enough buffer is one of the reasons to use pyhon - it solves that problem without issue. And I can't really be bothered to write up how to re-allocate a HBuf or TBuf. It's several lines of code that I always had to look up how to do each time I needed to use it (did I mention I spent my time working on graphics - reading/writing serial port is quite a long way from dealing with EGL, OpenGL and OpenVG).

Comment: Thanks, for your help anyway, I'll try getting this going myself by just allocating a seemingly large enough buffer and if that doesn't work I'll try python.

Comment: If anyone else could still help me though please do

Comment: Sorry, no. Ask questions here.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. I don't work for Symbian or any company related to Symbian any more, and if you want to ask question on SO, you are better off actually ASKING A QUESTION.